# How to use the new navigator.userAgentData to detect iPad or tablet?

Tags: javascript, ipad, tablet

Before I used:

```
const iPad = !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)/) || (navigator.platform === "MacIntel" && typeof navigator.standalone !== "undefined"));
const userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
const isTablet = /(ipad|tablet|(android(?!.*mobile))|(windows(?!.*phone)(.*touch))|kindle|playbook|silk|(puffin(?!.*(IP|AP|WP))))/.test(userAgent);
```

Now I get the notification in Chrome Dev Console:

> Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform

> A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
> To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.
> Note that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the properties is shown.

Docs from Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgentData

NEW with "navigator.userAgentData" are:

```
navigator.userAgentData.brands → Array
navigator.userAgentData.mobile → true/false
navigator.userAgentData.platform → e.g. "macOS" or "Windows"
```

How would I need to change the code above to detect iPad or tablet?

Answer (score 0):

Safari does not support the UserAgentData feature, and no version of Chrome on iOS supports it either.
So your best bet would be your existing code.

UserAgentData compatibility matrix (same as your link above):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgentData

UserAgentData support on IOS:
https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/issues/21308